# Date time format with milliseconds

Tags: excel

I have the following date time format: 2023.08.23 10:16:01,215
Excel custom formats basically break when they find the data and trying to force it into being just a date or an hour doesn't work either.

I just need to do a scatter plot with that being the x axis with it actually showing a date that isn't in 1900.

Sample data:

```
2023.08.22 17:44:08,847 17,2205
2023.08.22 21:49:00,785 17,2255
2023.08.23 01:53:51,874 17,3255
2023.08.23 05:58:42,499 17,1975
```

the default and custom date and time formats didn't work or just cut the day or hour out of the data. There is no support for creating a custom format in the web version and my company only provides us with the web version. Trying to just go with the custom format that doesn't have seconds results in the graph subtitle starting in 1900.01.01 and counting a day by each point of data. Also turning the date into a text didn't help.

Comment: Can you show us sample data, the cell format you used and the expected outcome? What should the x-axis of your chart be?

Comment: 2023.08.22 17:44:08,847 17,2205
2023.08.22 17:49:00,785 17,2255
2023.08.22 17:53:51,874 17,3255
2023.08.23 17:58:42,499 17,1975 The x axis should be the date, the problem is that there is more than one day involded in this test, so I cant just ignore it. Sorry for the format of the comment, I dont know how to jump a line in here yet

Comment: "There is no support for creating a custom format in the web version", this is true, but if you dowload the Excel file, add the custom format using Excel for Windows and upload again the resulting file on the web, the custom format works on the web too.

Comment: Have you considered rounding the date value? What about adjusting the bounds and the major and minor units of the X-axis?